# What is the probability/likelihood of a sample being drawn from a probability distribution over binary values

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, binary-data, likelihood

Suppose we have a known discrete probability distribution $X$ over $\{0,1\}^k$.
Given a sequence of binary values $e = (e_1, ..., e_n)\text{, where } e_i\in \{0,1\}^k$, what is the probability (or the likelihood) that $e$ was drawn from the Distribution $X$?
Is there for example a bound that tells us that such a sequence of samples $e$ is very unlikely to be drawn from $X$, and can thus be ignored?

Comment: So you're asking for the density function of all binary sequences of length $n$? Seems like they would all be equiprobable from how you have described the problem.  Are you thinking of a particular type of sequences (maybe sequences which have some sort of autocorrelation structure)?

Comment: @DemetriPananos Actually X is a noise distribution which is not uniform. So the values of $e_i$ are drawn non uniformally. X would have maybe some distribution function, but I'm aiming more at a general case.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you have not imposed any conditions on the distribution other than saying that it is a distribution on the set of binary vectors of length $k$.  Your distribution can therefore be expressed as a probability vector over the $2^k$ possible states of the random variable.  If the distribution is known, as you state, then presumably you can see exactly which outcomes are very unlikely.